# Double dehydration of a geminal diol

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I've recently came across this reaction and I am wondering about the mechanism. Could someone please help me? If you could give me the name of the reaction (if it has one) it should also be enough for me

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinacol_rearrangement

Comment: Technically, only a single dehydration is happening here; count the atoms in the reactant and product.

Comment: For future reference: consider learning how to use a molecular sketcher when reporting an organic reaction.  You find a comparison (e.g., http://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/) and listings (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecule_editor) and even find some not requiring a local installation to export, e.g., .png (https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/edit3/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It's a single dehydration with a carbocation intermediate that allows the five-membered ring to expand to a more stable six-membered ring.

Comment: While your answer is correct, we discourage here answering questioms violating homework policy.